# not able to add multiple images to canvas

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, canvas

I want that once image is selected from the gallery the user can move the image on the canvas and once satisfied by the position can add another image and so on.
I achieved the former part by tap event of canvas such that the image selected moves to the position where the users taps on the canvas.The difficulty is when i try to select another image to add to the canvas,instead of creating a new image it replaces the existing image on the canvas.The code is as follows

```
public void chooseImage_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK || e.ChosenPhoto == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Image img = new Image();
        SelectedBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(160,160);
        SelectedBitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        img.Source = SelectedBitmap;
        img.Name = "photo" + i++;
        imgSelected = true;
    }

 private void CollageCanvas_Tap(object sender,System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (imgSelected)
        {
            pt = e.GetPosition(CollageCanvas);
            img.Source = SelectedBitmap;
            img.Name = "photo" + i++; 
            CollageCanvas.Children.Remove(img);
            CollageCanvas.Children.Add(img);
            Canvas.SetLeft(img, pt.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(img, pt.Y);             
        }
    }
```

i want to know what is causing the new image to replace the already existing image and if possible correct the code to get the desired output.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing when you add a new photo in the ChooseImage_Completed method. You seem to be creating the image but never adding it as a child object of the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing all your code so I can't pinpoint the exact problem.  But it appears that only have one `img` reference.  That means that each time  the user selects an image, it's going into the same image element.

Here's how I'd solve the issue.  FWIW, using absolute positioning with `canvas.x`, and `canvas.y` is an old school approach.  It's more common to use a Translate Transform in XAML based apps.

XAML

```
<Grid Background='#FFEDB788'>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height='17*' />
        <RowDefinition Height='143*' />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Button Content='Choose Picture'
              HorizontalAlignment='Left'
              Margin='44,10,0,0'
              VerticalAlignment='Top'
              Click='Button_Click' />
      <Canvas HorizontalAlignment='Stretch'
              Width='Auto'
              Margin='3'
              x:Name='CollageCanvas'
              Grid.Row='1'
              VerticalAlignment='Stretch'
              Background='#FF080808' />

    </Grid>
```

**Code**

```
public MainPage() {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
  }

  private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
    photoChooserTask.Completed += 
      new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
  }

  private PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask;
  private WriteableBitmap SelectedBitmap;
  private int i;

  public void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e) {
    if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK || e.ChosenPhoto == null)
    {
      return;
    }
    // create the image control
    Image img = new Image() { Width = 160, Height = 160 };
    SelectedBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(160, 160);
    SelectedBitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
    img.Source = SelectedBitmap;
    img.Name = "photo" + i++;

    // add new image control to canvas
    CollageCanvas.Children.Add(img);

    // add the ManipulationDelta event to the new image
    img.ManipulationDelta += img_ManipulationDelta;

    // Add a transform to the image
    // Eventually this transform is used to move the image to a new position
    // See  the ManipulationDelta event handler
    img.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
  }

  private void img_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e) {
    // The ManipulationDelta occurs when the image is dragged to a new position
    var currentImage = sender as Image; // get the image
    var currentTransform = currentImage.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;  // get the transform

    currentTransform.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
    currentTransform.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
  }

  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    photoChooserTask.Show();
  }
```